# Command last does not show logins through sFTP, is there something similar or any logs?

Tags: sftp

When I run `last` I get something like:

```
user    pts/0        user.domain.provider Sat Feb 25 11:44   still logged in 
user    pts/0        user.domain.provider Thu Feb 23 16:38 - 16:39  (00:00)
...
```

But if I connect to the server with sFTP, this won't show up in this list. Are there any other logs or a different command?

Comment: which package you have used to configure sftp?

Comment: Hm... I don't really get your question. I use OpenSSH.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default configuration of syslogd sends all log messages related to authentication to /var/log/auth.log, which will include openssh-server's log messages.

Answer (score 3):

The `last` commands reads from /var/log/wtmp and its bad cousin /var/log/btmp, which according to man (`man wtmp`) are the login records.

Not all processes use this facility, so there may be other users logged to the system.

In the sftp case, I think that sshd does not consider scp or sftp as interactive sessions.

This was also discussed at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/20070/user-logged-in-by-sftp-does-not-show-up-in-w .

Comment: Your answer and the Q&A you linked explain some details, but unfortunately don't solve my question. scp/sftp is not considered as interactive session, so there is no entry in /var/log/btmp or /var/log/wtmp. But if I want to check if a user is connected through sftp, I still don't know how to enable logging or where to find the logs.

Comment: @lumbric check /var/log/auth.log

Comment: @geirha Oh wow, that was easy! If you convert it to an answer, I can award your answer for the bounty.

Answer (score 3):

Add pam_lastlog.so module at the beginning of session section in /etc/pam.d/sshd file as shown below.

```
# vi /etc/pam.d/sshd 
<snip..>
session    required     pam_lastlog.so
session    required     pam_selinux.so close
session    required     pam_loginuid.so
<snip..>
```

Ensure the option UsePAM is enabled in /etc/ssh/sshd_config. If not, make the changes and restart sshd service.

```
# vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
<snip..>
#UsePAM no
UsePAM yes
<snip..>

# service sshd restart
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.